# Image gallery issue jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

While I'm creating image gallery dynamically it isn't working. Here I'm adding all the images from a directory to a table dynamically. Its not completed now.

Here, I want to create image gallery dynamically and I'm new to jquery. see the partial code below.

sorry. The issue is image gallery is not working. while i clicking on a image it is going to displayed in another page.

in html,

```
<table id="tbl1">
</table>
```

in js,

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var bss = $('a[rel=blogslideshow]').bsShow({
      effect: 'Ladder',
      direction: 'horizontal'
    });
    var arr1 = ["sample_fussen.jpg", "sample_zakopane.jpg", "sample_wurzburg.jpg", "sample_keukenhof.jpg"];
    var cnt = 0;
    var festname = "slides";
    alert(arr1.length);
    var rows = arr1.length / 5; //here's your number of rows and columns
    var cols = 5;
    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
      var tr = $('<tr>');
      for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        if (cnt == arr1.length)
          break;
        var path = festname + '/' + arr1[cnt];
        $("<td><img src="
          "+path+"
          " width="
          100 " height="
          100 " alt="
          "/><h3><label><input type="
          radio " name="
          radio1 " value="
          ">Select Image</label></h3></td>").appendTo(tr);

        cnt++;
      }
      $('#tbl1').last().after(tr);
    }
    table.appendTo('body');
  })
</script>
```

I'm using reference link.

https://code.google.com/p/blogslideshow/downloads/list

Comment: What do you mean by `Not Working` ? what's the issue are you facing ? and it would be better if you can fiddle your code  : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sorry. The issue is image gallery is not working. while i clicking on a image it is going to displayed in another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are trying to initialize the anchor tag which you are not adding in table. Second, you are initializing your plugin before appending to body which never works because it is not present in DOM.

So try to add anchor tag in td and wrap your image to anchor tag like,

```
$("<td><a rel='blogslideshow' title='Your title' href='"+path+"'><img src='"+path+"' width='100'"+
      "height='100' alt=''/></a>"+
      "<h3><label><input type='radio'"+
      "name='radio1' value=''>Select Image</label>"+
      "</h3></td>").appendTo(tr);

after appending the data you need to re-initialize your plugin

var bss = $('a[rel=blogslideshow]').bsShow({
  effect: 'Ladder',
  direction: 'horizontal'
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/p0790ukc/)

Comment: then how to add an image path to a cell.

Comment: sorry, how to add a hyperlink to an image. is it the same way.

Comment: No hyperlink can only be added in `anchor tag` if you need to open a page on clicking an image then you need to use `window.location.href="page to open"` like `<img onclick="window.location.href='page.html'" ... />`

Comment: My code is worked perfectly without dynamic creation of a table. While i creating a table dynamically it's not working. https://code.google.com/p/blogslideshow/issues/list

Comment: Can you make an online demo for your working code non working code? If yes, then it is more easy to help you.

Comment: Later i have been changed it to the above code to make dynamic gallery.

Comment: What is the use of `table` here?

Comment: But I unable to removing rows from table. I am using like this $("#tbl1").remove();

Comment: Remove a row by its `id` or like `$('#tbl1 tr:last').remove()`. `$("#tbl1").remove();` will remove the table not the rows

Comment: even though it not effected.

Comment: Tell me the condition on your site.

Comment: Hi, I have seen the live demo. In gallery, images are in not coming in proper way. some images are coming like big and some are small. How to fix fixed width and height for an image.

Comment: Adjust it by css or show demo and condition for this